# 2-way Synchroniziation of Task Changes using EWS Managed API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a module to carry out 2-way synchronization between Tasks in a client system, with Task folders on an Exchange server, using Exchange Web Services.

It's working well, but I've come across a potential flaw in my approach.

When a Task change is saved in our system, I then update the Exchange server. This updates the SyncState value in EWS, leaving it out of sync with our local copy of the value. Hence, when we next call `syncFolderItems()` on EWS, the Task we just updated is returned to the client system as having been modified, and then is updated again (with the same values).

Is there any way to design the synchronization process to work around this?

Keeping a list of local Task Ids updated before calling the sync, which we can then compare to the TaskIds returned from the `syncFolderItems()` call, and then ignore would work, but doesn't seem particularly slick.

*I'm just starting work with Exchange Web Services, so apologies if I'm missing an easy trick here. Any advice on a better approach to achieving 2-way synchronization with EWS would be appreciated.*

Comment: Isn't it possible to compare if there are any difference between the new task vs the old task? If there are difference, then update else let it pass

Comment: Thanks Marcus, yeah I guess so. It seems equally 'un-slick', but there's a fairly limited number of fields to sync in Exchange Tasks, so I suppose that could do the trick.